# Как настроить MX на VPS для приема почты

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, dns, vps

У меня сервер VPX Ubuntu 16.04, на котором я установил mailutils (до этого установил exim4 - не знаю нужно ли было).
Работает -  `mail -aFrom:root@hadom.ru -s "subject1" "root@mysite.ru"` - приходит локально, работает на внешние почтовые ящики, работает отправка из php.
Что нужно прописать в настройках DNS MX - "почтовый клиент", "хост" с тем чтобы принимать сообщения?

Comment: Распишите подробно что вы делали, и что конкретно не получается, из текста вопроса вообще ничего не понятно.

Comment: из командной строки (как написано выше) я могу выслать сообщение на внешние почтовые ящики и на внутренний, что нужно прописать в настройках MX для того чтобы входящая/внешняя почта принималась?

Answer (score 0):

`mailutils` - это утилита для отправки почты из консоли, на прием и отправку сообщений с сервера никак не влияет.

Для того чтобы отправлять сообщения с сервера достаточно настроить `Exim` или `Postfix`.

`MX` запись нужна, чтобы другие сервера (не путать с почтовыми клиентами) могли отправлять на этот домен почту, т.е. заработал прием почты.

Как настроить `MX` запись - ищите в инструкциях конкретного регистратора/хостера, т.к. внешний вид/наименование параметров записи может отличаться.
Но в целом это выглядит так:

```
subdomain - @
server    - youserver.example.net
priority  - 0
```

Если предлагается ввести еще и `TTL` - можно оставить это поле пустым.

Чтобы почтовые клиенты могли подключаться к почтовому серверу, и могли просматривать входящие письма, нужно настроить `IMAP` или `POP`. Как это делается, читайте инструкции в интернете.

P.S. Рекомендую сразу почитать, что такое [SPF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework), [DMARC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC) и [DKIM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) записи, и как все это дело настроить.